# replicate yearly statewide value for balanced panel

Tags: r, time-series, replication

I am trying to replicate the total value of the year to the next year value. My dataset looks like this:

| year | state | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Texas | 1 | 2 |
| 2000 | NY | 3 | 4. |
| 2010 | Texas | 10 | 20 |
| 2010 | NY | 30 | 40 |
| 2020 | Texas | 15 | 25 |
| 2020 | NY | 35 | 45 |

I want to make the year continuous from 2000, 2001, 2022, 2003 etc to 2010 the same values of 2000. From 2010, to 2020 the same values of 2010. I want to make it balanced panel.

Answer (score 0):

By `state` and `year` group, you can replicate rows 10 times, if the year<2020, then re-sequence the year:

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(n,d) d[rep(1,n)]

setDT(df)[, f(fifelse(.BY$year<2020,10,1), .SD),.(state,year)][
  ,year:=seq(min(year),by=1,length.out=.N),state][]
```

Output:

```
   <char> <int> <int> <num>
 1:  Texas  2000     1     2
 2:  Texas  2001     1     2
 3:  Texas  2002     1     2
 4:  Texas  2003     1     2
 5:  Texas  2004     1     2
 6:  Texas  2005     1     2
 7:  Texas  2006     1     2
 8:  Texas  2007     1     2
 9:  Texas  2008     1     2
10:  Texas  2009     1     2
11:     NY  2000     3     4
12:     NY  2001     3     4
13:     NY  2002     3     4
14:     NY  2003     3     4
15:     NY  2004     3     4
16:     NY  2005     3     4
17:     NY  2006     3     4
18:     NY  2007     3     4
19:     NY  2008     3     4
20:     NY  2009     3     4
21:  Texas  2010    10    20
22:  Texas  2011    10    20
23:  Texas  2012    10    20
24:  Texas  2013    10    20
25:  Texas  2014    10    20
26:  Texas  2015    10    20
27:  Texas  2016    10    20
28:  Texas  2017    10    20
29:  Texas  2018    10    20
30:  Texas  2019    10    20
31:     NY  2010    30    40
32:     NY  2011    30    40
33:     NY  2012    30    40
34:     NY  2013    30    40
35:     NY  2014    30    40
36:     NY  2015    30    40
37:     NY  2016    30    40
38:     NY  2017    30    40
39:     NY  2018    30    40
40:     NY  2019    30    40
41:  Texas  2020    15    25
42:     NY  2020    35    45
     state  year    x1    x2
```